# IIS gives localhost URI instead of server name

Tags: iis

IIS7 serving .Net web application (simple database site).

I have a weird issue where the backgroundimage(URL) property of a element will be served as "http:\localhost" instead of "http:\servername". This is a problem because when a user connects to my site, "localhost" would be their workstation, not the IIS server. So the image (in this case a button) is blank.

The issue is intermittent, recycling the application pool seems to fix the issue for a time and then it comes back. IIS server also runs a SQL instance which eats ~28/36GB RAM.

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: It is ok for you to be served an image from local host as it is your machine being hosted locally. Local host can be useful because most every server you deploy your website to will likely understand that localhost is itself. Another machine would have to use the public facing domain/network name of the server hosting your web site.

Comment: In this case I need the URL to be the servername, not localhost. My users do not have a local site, they are accessing it via the server hostname.

Comment: You have to set the domain name (url) in IIS and bind it to the web site. Localhost is kind of like a shortcut. If you path something using localhost it can work on any server that has that configured. However, any resource accessed from the outside will have to use the domain name that you set up for the site in IIS. Also you need to find the image above and remove the hardcoded "localhost" and exchange it with a dynamic path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this you need to search for all locations where "http:\localhost" is hardcoded in your web app and replace it with a dynamic path. Even though localhost can work in your code if it is relative to the server, there are times when it will not work, such as in a link. You should get in the habit of never hardcoding your urls.

If you are using MVC -

```
value = Url.Content("~/Images/MyImage.png");
```

If you are using Forms -

```
value = ResolveUrl("~/") + "Images/MyImage.png"
```

Or relative pathing -

```
value = "~/Images/MyImage.png"
```

Comment: I don't believe it's hardcoded, at least not to my knowledge. The only place we have a hard-coded URL is in our DB and that contains the correct "servername" URL. 

What happens is my users get to the site via http:\\servername\site . 

When they go to a specific element on a certain page, IIS serves the URL as "http:\\localhost" instead of the correct URL. So IIS is serving the correct URL in certain context.

Comment: If you are using one of the above schemes then you would see a reference to an image in the form of --> <img src='/YourRoot/Images/MyImage.png' alt="title" />. You say it is coming over the wire as localhost. Can you dig into the code where that link is being generated and post the markup?

Comment: here's the element in question:

<td id="ctl13_horizontalContainerInMiddlePane_ctl02_ctl01_RequestPermissionWizardStep11_varonisButtonSelectUser_htmlCellSinglelineMidText" class="ButtonCellMid" style="height:22;" nowrap="nowrap">Change Users</td>

the computed CSS:

.ButtonMainTable .ButtonCellMidurl("http://localhost/DP/Images/Buttons/Regular/Mid_2.gif")


As you can see, for whatever reason the URL is served as "Localhost" and not ServerName. If I manually edit the URL in Dev tools and change "localhost" to "servername", the img source becomes valid and works.

Comment: That is a forms control and it has a reference to an image via css, it appears. You need to scan the code for ButtonCellMidurl and change it to a relative path. Changing "localhost/DP/Images/Buttons/Regular/Mid_2‌​.gif" to be generated as "~/DP/Images/Buttons/Regular/Mid_2‌​.gif" should work.

Comment: I updated the web forms part as it would originally return the physical path.

Comment: Thanks Ross, however as I said this is intermittent. The issue doesn't always occur so it's probably not hardcoded anywhere. I haven't been able to determine the exact context where is occurs yet. 

It just seems to pop up every once in a while, resetting the application pools fixes the issue, so I'm assuming it's somehow resource related.

Comment: I don't know why server load would have an effect on the pathing of a resource, however, best of luck on solving your issue.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's a weird problem. Somehow resetting the app pools makes the URL show up correctly with the server name. I almost want to say it's some kind of browser cache issue but I can't prove that yet. Thanks for the help.